# How do I get a picture (flag) in the same line as some text?

Tags: html, css, image, line

Probably a stupid question, but how can I get an image (in this case a flag) in the same line as some text see image?

[image]

My HTML code so far:

```
<h4>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c3/Flag_of_France.svg/30px-Flag_of_France.svg.png" alt="France" height="13px" width="20px"> FRA
</h4>
```

Comment: Please show us what you tried so far.

Comment: this is HTML/CSS 101; question's too broad, look for and try something, that way you'll "learn" something.

Comment: If you don't have any code than you want to to be reviewed and you want to do it from scratch instead then check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639388/how-to-put-html-picture-text-on-the-same-line-in-a-div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```css
img {
  height:20px;
  width:30px;
  display: inline;
}

span {
  display: inline;
  height:20px;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
        <img src="http://www.defendersofthescroll.com/images/franceflag.gif"  />
        <span>
           FRA
        </span>
```

Comment: Tried it, but the image stays in original size.

Comment: you need to modify the `height` and `width` attributes on the `img` tag with the values you need :)

Comment: Are your problem fixed?

Comment: No it still is in original size, even when I modify the height and width attributes on the img tag.

Comment: Can you post your code here, or in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) so I can help you more.

Answer (score 1):

Changes based on your code:

```html
<h4>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c3/Flag_of_France.svg/30px-Flag_of_France.svg.png" alt="France" height="13px" width="20px" display="inline"> <span display="inline">FRA</span>
</h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <span><h4><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c3/Flag_of_France.svg/30px-Flag_of_France.svg.png" height="10px" width="10px">fra </h4></span>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: why another answer? just edit your other one http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41403355/edit and delete this one.

Comment: That answer uses Table, this might add an additional option.

Comment: you should have added it then. I don't see the point in having 2 separate answers.